# How to Write jaxb binding from wsdl

Tags: web-services, jaxb, wsdl, jax-ws, jax-rs

Hi i want to write jaxb binding for below wsdl:message in wsdl.

```
<xs:element name="getSampleForBknumRequest">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
        getSampleForBknumRequest Request - this is the full message document passed into the service
    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="Comn:BaseRequestType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="bk" type="comn:bkType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="getSampleForBknumResponse">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            this is the full message document returned from the service
    </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="Comn:ResponseType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="org" type="org:LocationDataType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The corresponding wsdl:message for the above is

```
    <wsdl:message name="getSampleForRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="getSampleForBknumRequest" element="ns1:DB_getSampleForBknumRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getSampleForResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="getSampleForBknumResponse" element="ns1:DB_getSampleForBknumResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
```

and the corresponding wsdl:operation is

```
    <wsdl:operation name="getSamForBknum">
    <wsdl:input name="getSampleForRequest" message="tns:getSampleForRequest"/>
    <wsdl:output name="getSampleForResponse" message="tns:getSampleForResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

continuation:

```
    <wsdl:operation name="getSampleForBk">
    <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
    <wsdl:input name="getSampleForRequest">
    <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="getSampleForResponse">
    <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

I am new to webservices so i don't know how to right jaxb binding for the above.Usually we will give xsd in schema location of jaxb:binding,Here i don't have any xsd's eveything in a same wsdl file.
Please someone guide me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this Link. One Option is to use Inline Customization

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148366